# How to count row_number by groups

Tags: postgresql

Here is the example of the table:

```
id color time
1  pink  2
1  pink  1 
1  red   4
1  green 5 
1  green 3 
2  green 1 
2  orange 2
2  pink  3
```

The desired result

```
1  pink  1  3
1  pink  2  3
1  red   3  2
1  green 4  1
1  green 5  1 
2  green 1  3 
2  orange 2 2 
2  pink  3  1
```

I tried to do it like this
`select *, row_number() over (partition by id,color order by time desc)`
But it returns another outcome
from

Comment: why pink serial is 3 and red 2. My observation pink will 2 and red will 3. Please explain

Comment: @RahulBiswas sorry,miswrote the table, corrected mistake

Comment: will your logic change id wise or if many ids in your tables like 3, 4 etc? for id = 1 where pink = 3 but it would be 2 and red will 3; for id = 2 where green = 3.. What the logic behind this.

Comment: No, it wont change